# How can I access Dialogflow API V2 in Android with Service Account?

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

In my project, I am trying to use Dialogflow API V2 in my Android app.
But there is no SDK for Android.

So I use HttpRequest to access Dialogflow Rest API directly.
In this case, I can't find solutions to access Rest API with service account.
Is there any solutions to fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

To access `Dialogflow Rest API V2` you need to use below in your app's `build.gradle` file:

**For DialogFlow API V2**:

```
implementation 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7@aar'
```

**For DialogFlow API V1**:

```
implementation 'ai.api:libai:1.6.12'
```

Read [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client#overview) for more information.

BUT **DialogFlow V2 SDK is not available as of now(July 12, 2018) for Android** here is the [official information](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide-api):

> V2 SDKs are available in Node.js, Python, Java, Go, Ruby, C#, and PHP.
>   For more information, please see Dialogflow's [SDK page](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks).

Comment: Its still not there.